# Photo Library is not accessible only camera option available swift code

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

I am using Swift 5 code and in code I have to capture image. My source type would be `.camera` or `.photoLibrary`. I have perfectly set everything even the permission settings in `Info.plist` but for unseen reason photo library is not accessible for selecting image. Only camera option is available every time. Please suggest and look into my code what am I doing wrong?

Permission Info.plist:

```
Privacy - Photo Library Additions Usage Description
Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description
Privacy - Media Library Usage Description
Privacy - Camera Usage Description
```

Code:

```
var imagePicker: UIImagePickerController!


 enum ImageSource {
        case photoLibrary
        case camera
    }

    //MARK: - Take image
    func takePhoto() {
        guard UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.camera) else {
            selectImageFrom(.photoLibrary)
            return
        }
        selectImageFrom(.camera)
    }

    func selectImageFrom(_ source: ImageSource){
        imagePicker =  UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        switch source {
        case .camera:
            imagePicker.sourceType = .camera
        case .photoLibrary:
            imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        }
        present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You always prioritize camera in your guard

```
//MARK: - Take image
func takePhotoLib() { 
    guard UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.photoLibrary) else { 
        return
    }
    selectImageFrom(.photoLibrary)
}

//MARK: - Take image
func takePhotoCamera() {
    guard UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.camera) else { 
        return
    }
    selectImageFrom(.camera)
}
```

Comment: Thank you I have tried to implemented your way but every time `photoLibrary`is accessible but no `camera` However if I change switch source statement to `imagePicker.sourceType = source `  it gives me error.

Answer (score 0):

Change the argument type from `ImageSource` to `UIImagePickerController.SourceType`

```
func selectImageFrom(_ source: UIImagePickerController.SourceType){
        imagePicker =  UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        switch source {
        case .camera:
            imagePicker.sourceType = .camera
        case .photoLibrary:
            imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        }
        present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

It should work now.

Sorry, you seem to check whether the device have a camera and then proceed to select that. Show an action sheet for the user to select one of them. It would work.

use this function:

```
func showOptions(sender: AnyObject) {
    let alertController = UIAlertController.init(title: "Choose Option", message: "", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
    let cameraAction = UIAlertAction.init(title: "Camera", style: .default) { (action) in
        self.selectImageFrom(.camera)
    }
    alertController.addAction(cameraAction)
    let photoLibraryAction = UIAlertAction.init(title: "Photo Library", style: .default) { (action) in
        self.selectImageFrom(.photoLibrary)
    }
    alertController.addAction(photoLibraryAction)
    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction.init(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel) { (action) in
    }
    alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
    present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I updated your code `argument type` but still only camera available not photo library. On camera screen it shows only cancel, mid button for photo and camera swapping Front or back. No option to choose photo from library.

Comment: Sorry @NewBieMobile , you seem to check whether the device have a camera and then proceed to select that. Show an action sheet for the user to select one of them. It would work.

Comment: if you just remove the guard statement you'd get that. You are checking whether camera is available then choosing it and returning, hence no photo library access.

Comment: I am checking on my mobile, camera works fine but not for photo Library. But if I removed camera option `.photolibrary` works.

Comment: yeah see my comment above. Like I said, You are checking whether camera is available then choosing it and returning, hence no photo library access as the code will never execute.

Comment: Yes I am going to. I will update you in 10 minutes.

Comment: @NewBieMobile Glad to be of help. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this function is shorter and reduces the extra code.

```
func selectImageFrom(_ source: UIImagePickerController.SourceType) {
    guard UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(source) else {
        return
    }
    let imagePicker =  UIImagePickerController()
    imagePicker.delegate = self
    imagePicker.sourceType = source
    present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
      func selectimage(_ sender: UIButton)
    {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Take Photo", style: .default, handler: { _ in
            self.openCamera()
        }))

        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Choose Photo", style: .default, handler: { _ in
            self.openGallary()
        }))

        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction.init(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))

        //If you want work actionsheet on ipad then you have to use popoverPresentationController to present the actionsheet, otherwise app will crash in iPad
        switch UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom {
        case .pad:
            alert.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = sender
            alert.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = sender.bounds
            alert.popoverPresentationController?.permittedArrowDirections = .up
        default:
            break
        }

        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }


    //MARK: - Open the camera
    func openCamera(){
        if(UIImagePickerController .isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera)){
            imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera

            //If you dont want to edit the photo then you can set allowsEditing to false
            // imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
            imagePicker.delegate = self
            imagePicker.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
            self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)


        }
        else{
            let alert  = UIAlertController(title: "Warning", message: "You don't have camera", preferredStyle: .alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))
            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }

func openGallary(){
        if(UIImagePickerController .isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary)){
            imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary
            self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = true
            //If you dont want to edit the photo then you can set allowsEditing to false
            // imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
            imagePicker.delegate = self
            imagePicker.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
            self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)


        }
```